# Stackdump in C++ not showing the stack trace

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, stack, stack-trace

I have an app that crashes sometimes and creates the next file: (APP.exe.stackdump)

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=6BA4B246
eax=67452301 ebx=EFCDAB89 ecx=98BADCFE edx=10325476 esi=FFFFFFFF edi=98BADCFE
ebp=FFFFFFFF esp=01A2C928 program=C:\APP.exe, pid 168, thread unknown (0x13E8)
cs=001B ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003B gs=0000 ss=0023
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
End of stack trace
```

I'm compiling with g++ in Windows, Ubuntu and Centos. The error happens sometimes only, inside a thread, there is anyway to get the stack trace of where is happening? Or any extra info?

**Update 1:**

I can capture it with:

```
signal(SIGSEGV, sigHandler);
```

But still I don't have stacktrace info.

Comment: You are compiling in Windows, Ubuntu and Centos. Are you getting errors in all 3 or just 1?

Comment: I might be mistaken, but `esp` looks reasonable. Did you look there? A lack of a stack trace merely means that the top level return value could not be found automatically, but that only requires a very small stack corruption (one pointer)

Comment: seems to be stack corruption.. can you reproduce it in `gdb` if compiled with `-g`?

Comment: @yi_H, I'm compiling in DEBUG mode with -g. I don't know how to find where is the error, I need debug info like stacktrace of the last functions executed. Vjo, This errors sometimes happens in Centos but I see them more in Windows XP.

Comment: @yi_H In gdb sometimes breaks in an unknown signal with no stack info, only asm code (md5_block_asm_data_order+38: mov (%esi),%ebp).

Comment: If you could send objdump result near eip and some stack raw dump around esp in hex several kb, I might be able to unwind manually

Comment: Isn't EBP a bit whacky in that dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or any extra info?

Use valgrind or efence.  Both are very good at finding usage of wild pointers at the time of dereference, instead of later when the corrupted data is used.

Comment: I tried in the past valgrind with this app, but breaks in some point of this app. I'll try efence. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities why stack trace is not available:

1. you compiled your code without stack frame (as far as I remember this is default behaviour for x86_64 code generated by gcc/g++)
2. you corrupted your stack (stack overflow ;))
3. There is nothing to trace ;) (you are in code executed before or after main and you haven't entered any functions yet or already returned from them)

Judging from a fact that EBP=FFFFFFFF I would go for #2 unless the problem exists in low level C or assembler code which touches EBP. Can you provide dissassembly from a dump?